# Wifi card becomes unreadable after laptop enters sleep mode in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, suspend

I just installed Linux on my new Lenovo Flex laptop, and I've never used Linux before. I set up dual boot, so I can boot into either Windows 10 or Ubuntu. Everything seemed to be working great at first, but I soon realized that if my laptop goes to sleep while running Ubuntu, the wifi stops working. More specifically, no networks show up when I search for them.

Once the wifi disconnects, neither rebooting nor running `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` seems to fix things. The only way I can get the wifi to reconnect is by booting up into Windows 10 (where the wifi is working perfectly fine), and then rebooting back into Ubuntu.

Because the wifi works well on Windows 10, I assumed this must be a driver issue for Ubuntu. How do I reinstall the driver for the wifi card? Or can anyone help me find a solution to this issue of wifi not working after sleeping?

From what I can tell, my wifi device on this laptop is RTL8822BE. 
I really would like to learn Linux, but this has been incredibly frustrating to work around constantly having to reboot twice every time my computer goes to sleep...

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and post URL after running the script and doing `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by altering a bios setting. For me, changing to 'Legacy boot mode' resolved this issue entirely. It wasn't recognizing the wifi card as a result of a bios setting rather than missing drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 'firmware-realtek' package. Right now it's getting the firmware blob from Windows. It hangs on to it until Linux goes to sleep. When it wakes up, it can't reload the firmware, because it isn't there.